# Image keeps moving to the right or left depending on resize

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having some trouble with keeping my image fixed while resizing. I'm pretty new to HTML and CSS but I'll try my best to explain.

I have this HTML and CSS Code:

```css
#container {
  min-width:150px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


.sky-img {
  width: 100px;
  height:auto;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
   <div class="div-wrapper">
     <img src="img/sky.jpg" class="sky-img">
    </div> 
</div>
```

I was experimenting with some things that I found on this website but nothing was working. Basically, I have an image that I want to appear in one place at all times, always in the top middle, no matter how big or small I resize my window. Currently, the image stays fine until I hit a certain size when I resize my window, and it starts slowly moving right while I am resizing my window. Then it stays at this new position until I reach another point where it starts to keeping moving right again.

I want to know how I can get this image to stay in one place even if I resize my window. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with setting `min-width` on `.sky-img`. Just limit it to `width`. min-width makes it flexible yet the `margin: 0 auto;` works with a limited width.

```css
#container {
width:150px;
height: 200px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.sky-img {
  width: 100px;
  height:auto;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
   <div class="div-wrapper">
     <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512926182919-fd3c6c6f01bb?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=f48d3bba705f3d16eb60a05ab4b2fe4d" class="sky-img">
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: This worked for the most part! I only have one more question if you can answer it, after 768px my navigation bar starts to overlap with the picture, and I'm trying to use media query to move it up but it's not moving up. Do you know how I can shift it up?